# How to use Function in the INSERT INTO Statement [SQL SERVR 2016]

Tags: sql-server, function, call, scalar

The title says it all. I need to create a table(ID, FirstName, LastName) that will be populated with randomly generated 'words' that have a random length and are created from my 'alphabet'. Each word needs to be randomly generated by the DB. The whole table should have 1,000,000 rows.

Let me fill you in what I have done so far.

1. Created a **VIEW** that generates a random number:

   `CREATE VIEW [dbo].[RANDOM]
      AS SELECT RAND() RandomResult`
2. Created a **SCALAR FUNCTION** that generates a random lengh 'word' from the set of determined 'letters' :

   ```
     CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[WordGenerator] (@RandomWord VARCHAR(MAX))
     RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
     AS BEGIN

      DECLARE @Alphabet VARCHAR(33) = 'abcdefghijklmnoprstuówxyzęąśłżźćń',
              @StrLength INT,
              @LoopCount INT,
              @RandomString VARCHAR(MAX),
              @AlphabetLength INT;

       SELECT @StrLength = (SELECT RandomResult FROM dbo.Random) * 4 + 7, @LoopCount = 0, @RandomString = '', @AlphabetLength = LEN(@Alphabet);

        WHILE (@LoopCount < @StrLength)
               BEGIN
                 SELECT @RandomString = @RandomString + SUBSTRING(@Alphabet, CONVERT(INT, (SELECT RandomResult FROM dbo.Random) * @AlphabetLength), 1)
                 SET @LoopCount = @LoopCount + 1;  
               END

      RETURN @RandomString;
   END
   ```
3. Now I want to use this FUNCTION called 'WordGenerator' in the INSERT INTO Clause however it simply does not work because I am not able to call it.

**How can I call my Function** that every single time it is supposed to generate a new, random word?

Using `SELECT TOP 1 RandomWord FROM dbo.WordGenerator()` does not work.

Using  `SELECT dbo.WordGenerator()` does not work.

Using `SELECT * FROM dbo.WordGenerator()` does not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's not a table-valued function. So just call SELECT dbo.WordGenerator()... not sure why you have a parameter in there.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your function expects a parameter that is never used and not passed in. So change it to:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[WordGenerator] ()
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Alphabet VARCHAR(33) = 'abcdefghijklmnoprstuówxyzęąśłżźćń',
    DECLARE @StrLength INT;
    DECLARE @LoopCount INT;
    DECLARE @RandomString VARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @AlphabetLength INT;

    SELECT @StrLength = RandomResult * 4 + 7, @LoopCount = 0, @RandomString = '', @AlphabetLength = LEN(@Alphabet)
    FROM dbo.Random;

    WHILE @LoopCount < @StrLength
    BEGIN
        SELECT @RandomString = @RandomString + SUBSTRING(@Alphabet, CONVERT(INT, RandomResult * @AlphabetLength), 1)
        FROM dbo.Random;

        SET @LoopCount += 1;  
    END;

    RETURN @RandomString;
END;
```

And then just call it like that: `SELECT dbo.WordGenerator();` That's the way you call a scalar function.

`SELECT * FROM dbo.WordGenerator();` this way you're calling table valued functions.

Comment: YOU nailed it! I have never thought about it. It works now, I can call it! Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help! :)

Comment: Please accept @Evaldas answer. This will help ensure all others not to view this question since he already provided one  :-)